# Match all lines starting with a space up till a line that doesnt start with a space

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, regex-negation

So I have a few lines like such:

```
tag1:
 line1word1 lineoneanychar
 line2word1
tag2:
 line1word1 ....
 line2word1 .....
```

I am trying to build a java regex that extracts all the data under the tags. i.e:

```
String parsed1 = line1word1 lineone\nline2word1
String parsed2 = line1word1 ....\nline2word1 .....
```

I believe the right way to do this is using something like this, but I haven't quite got it right:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("tag1:\n( {1}.*)\n(?!\\w+)", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(clean_data);
    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be something like that

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "tag1:\n" 
            + " line1word1 lineoneanychar\n" 
            + " line2word1\n"
            + "tag2:\n" 
            + " line1word1 ....\n" 
            + " line2word1 .....\n";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("tag\\d+:$\\n((?:^\\s.*?$\\n)+)", Pattern.DOTALL|Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Remember to escape \\ in your regex.

\d is a number

\s a space

(?:something) is for making a group that won't be a real 'group' in the matcher

Comment: So I get most of the regex, but what does ?$ do? I realize $ is generally end of statement. So (?:^\\s.*?$\\n) is --> as long as line is not starting with a space following by anything and [?] ending with a newline.

Comment: The ? is not related to the end of line char ($), but to indicate that .* is non-greedy. Otherwise, .* will match everything 'till the end of the entire String